# Saving a setting to MySettings and exiting the program isn't working

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with saving a setting to My Project and then exiting my program with an 'End' statement.  If I save the setting but don't execute the end statement, everything works.  If I save the setting and then execute the 'End', the setting doesn't get saved.  Here's  some code that illustrates the problem:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'reads the last setting correctly
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.MySetting
End Sub

Private Sub btnWrite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWrite.Click
    'write value, don't exit; works
    My.Settings.MySetting = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub btnWriteEnd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWriteEnd.Click
    'write value and end; fails
    My.Settings.MySetting = TextBox1.Text
    End
End Sub
```

End Class

When I execute the code, whatever was last in My.Settings.MySetting appears in TextBox1.  If I change the text in the textbox and click on the 'Write' button and manually exit the program by clicking on the 'X',  the new text appears properly changed when I execute the program again.  If I change the text and exit programmatically by clicking on 'WriteEnd', the changed setting text doesn't get written to 'MySetting'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to add `My.Settings.Save()` into the click handler. Incidentally I suspect that calling `End` immediately terminates the application and may not free up memory and close files properly.. It may be better to try calling `Application.Exit` as this should do the above along with garbage collection etc.

Comment: Remove the `End` keyword.... [Have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement) a good read about that here. What you can do instead is call `Close`...

Answer (score 2):

Settings will be saved automatically at shutdown by default, so there's generally no need to call `Save`. `End` is definitely the issue. NEVER use `End`. Call `Close` on the startup form or call `Application.Exit`. I compare `End` with a bouncer grabbing someone by the scruff of the neck and throwing them out, spilling their drink on everyone and leaving their jacket behind, rather than asking them to leave of their own accord.